# String Exception is not being caught?

Tags: apex, exception

Some how nothing is being caught. Not sure, but it could be not understanding how exception really works.
So I have a method that does everything including querying, than finally does an update to an opportunity record

```
public void createAlert(){
    try{
        for (List<OpportunityLineItem> oliList : [Select oli.id from OpportunityLineItem oli Where oli.OpportunityId = :oppId]){

        //some logic
        }   
        //some logic
        update updateOpp;
    } catch (System.StringException e) {
        system.debug('Exception===>' + e.getMessage());
    }                                                   
}
```

I am invoking this method from the develop console right now like this :

```
Alert opp = new Alert('aaaaaaaaa');
opp.createAlert();
```

I get this error:

```
11:36:07:147 FATAL_ERROR System.StringException: Invalid id: aaaaaaaaa
```

But it never caught the exception, so I never got the "Exception===>" debug message.

Comment: What does the constructor method of your Alert class look like? It could be the exception is happening there rather than in the createAlert function.

Comment: Less likely, but possible, is if in DC your Apex Code log level is INFO or higher - then the debug message won't appear

Comment: It appears to me, based on how you have your brackets are set up, including having logic within a for loop containing your Select Query, it could very well be that you could have an invalid ID exception thrown before it can be trapped by your catch block. You may need to set up the try-catch differently.

Comment: As Doug mentioned, can you post the code for your Alert class?

Comment: All the constructor is doing is setting the Id. This is what my constructor looks like:   public OppAlert(ID opp){
  oppId = opp;  
 }

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's a little lazy, but instead of catching specifically the StringException, you could just catch Exception, which is a catch-all bucket:

```
} catch (Exception e) {
    system.debug('Exception===>' + e.getMessage());
}
```

Is that sufficient for your needs?

Also, your constructor is expecting an Id - and you are not passing in a valid Id. Salesforce does check Ids for legitimate formats. Pass in something that will pass the test, such as 005000000000000000.

Comment: ... additionally, this `catch` and ignore pattern should be corrected. Not presenting a message of some sort to the user is generally considered bad practice.

Comment: Yes, that's true. I was more focusing on switching from StringException to Exception. Adding a message would be good, but seems beyond the scope of this question, since I was just adjusting one line of the provided code.

Comment: I think the "Also...." part of the comment is probably more valuable and may well warrant it being an answer on its own. There really is a type mismatch there.

Comment: I hear ya! There is nothing wrong with the answer, it's spot-on. Just wanted to throw it out there so that it did not go unsaid. :-)

Comment: Well, initially I did use just the all-catch all Exception, but it catch anything. So I assume maybe I should try something more specific and see if it catches it.